# Extract value from href tag in table using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table with a td like below. I want to extract the value "abl" the value of symbol from href tag.

```
<td>
<a href="../detail.php?symbol=ABL">Ace Bank Limited</a>
</td>
```

I can simply extract Ace Bank Limited using $td->nodeValue; but how can I extract abl using php only?

Comment: how you getting $td->nodeValue;? in php

Comment: `$td->attributes` will get all attributes. So iterate over that and get the href one to get the full url. Then you can use regex to get ABL

Comment: I didn't get anything back from $td->attributes

Answer (score 0):

try with `DOM`

```
$html = '<td><a href="../detail.php?symbol=ABL">Ace Bank Limited</a></td>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $tag) {
    $anchor = $tag->getAttribute('href'); 
    $text = explode('=', $anchor);
    echo $text[1]; //ABL
}
```

or using `preg_match`

```
preg_match('/=([^\"]+)/', $html, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; //ABL
```

Comment: yes it works if I define $html but I can't define the variable like $html = '<td><a href="../detail.php?symbol=ABL">Ace Bank Limited</a></td>'; as it different in each column so firstly I have to extract "<td><a href="../detail.php?symbol=ABL">Ace Bank Limited</a></td>" ?  and how can i do that?

Comment: set your all html to a variable and echo that and also variable pass in loadhtml($var)

Comment: use preg_match_all('/=([^\"]+)/', $html, $matches); This will list all that is matched.

Comment: @Ramesh_D yes but in OP case it only match one

Answer (score 0):

Try with Regex:- `preg_match(/symbol=([^\"]+)/, $table_data, $matched)`